# Regex in C# to get only money or decimal with dot and comma

Tags: c#, regex

Could you help me to get this data:

```
1.529,11
(231,48)
21.945,51
```

from this expression:

```
Saldo em Tesouraria 1.529,11 100,00% 0,00%
Custo SELIC 17/04/23 (231,48)
Diferimento de despesa de TAXA CVM com vencimento 29/12/23 21.945,51
```

I'am using this regex

```
(?:((\(|[0-9])+[\.|,]))+\d+([\s]|\))
```

but I'm not having success to take all data.

Thanks

Comment: Playground: https://regex101.com/r/xGMLXZ/1

Comment: Try `\([\d.]+,\d\d\)|[\d.]+,\d\d(?!%)`.

Answer (score 0):

I did this. The regex used was:

```
(?:((\(|[0-9])+[\.|,]))+\d+([\s]|\)|\d)(?!%)
```

In C#, the code I wrote is this:

```
Regex valores = new Regex(@"(?:((\(|[0-9])+[\.|,]))+\d+([\s]|\)|\d)(?!%)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`(\d{1,3}\.)*\d{1,3},\d{2}(?!%)|\((\d{1,3}\.)*\d{1,3},\d{2}(?!%)\)`

If you don't need the parenthesis, you can drop everything after `|` (including `|`).

Check here: https://regex101.com/r/EdkwKr/1

Answer (score 0):

As a reference, you can use the following pattern.

```
(?<=^| )(?:\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d{2})(?!%)|\(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d{2})\))(?= |$)
```

This will match the following.  In which, the decimal comma and 2 digits are required.
And, I guess, technically there should also be a check for leading zero's, which I didn't add—it may be irrelevant at that point.

```
123.456.789,01
12.345.678,90
1.234.567,89
123,45
12,34
1,23
```

And, will not match these,

```
123
123,4
1.2.3,4
1.23,45
100,00%
1,00%
1%
```